# How to return values from database/model after post request in Django Rest framework

Tags: django, post, django-rest-framework, get

I recently started working on django. I am trying to send a location name via post method and then display the list of values from the model on the url or api end point.

I am unable to do it. When I send a post request I am not able to view the results on the url/api end point. It displays GET menthod not allowed.

This is my views.py

```
class location_details(APIView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        lid = json.loads(request.body).get('location_name')
        queryset = customer.objects.filter(location_id= lid)
        serializer_class = customer_details
        data = serializers.serialize('json', queryset)
        return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json')
```

This is my serialisers.py -

```
class customer_details(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = customer
        fields = ('location_id', 'cid','name','age', 'gender')
```

How can I display the values based on a post request? I want to display the list of customers in a location and the location has to be passed as a post.

I am stuck with this issue for a long time.

Comment: what is your `serializers` ?

Comment: I added it in the question

Comment: have you tried to use ListModelMixin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming `customer_details` is your serializer which is responsible for serialize data.

```py
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status

class location_details(APIView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        lid = request.data['location_name']
        queryset = customer.objects.filter(location_id= lid)
        serialize =  customer_details(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serialize.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```